# How to prevent duplicate pair to be inserted into lookup table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make relationship between `CAR` and `ITEM` tables.

Since a car can have the same component as other cars, and an item can be used in many cars. I decide to use many-to-many relationship for this issue.

This issue force me to remove `PK` from both `car_idcar` and `item_list_iditem_list` on the middle table.

**But...How I can prevent entry of duplicate pair(`red box below`)from being inserted**

Additional info as @Barmar requested:

```
CREATE TABLE `car_item` (
   `id_car_item` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `car_idcar` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `item_list_iditem_list` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_car_item`),
   UNIQUE KEY `car_idcar_UNIQUE` (`car_idcar`),
   UNIQUE KEY `item_list_iditem_list_UNIQUE` (`item_list_iditem_list`),
   KEY `fk_car_has_item_list_item_list1_idx` (`item_list_iditem_list`),
   KEY `fk_car_has_item_list_car1_idx` (`car_idcar`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_car_has_item_list_car1` FOREIGN KEY (`car_idcar`) REFERENCES `car` (`idcar`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `fk_car_has_item_list_item_list1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_list_iditem_list`) REFERENCES `item_list` (`iditem_list`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Full schema creating script here: http://pastebin.com/1vPYxswd

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have unique keys on each column, you should have a unique key on the combination of columns. This allows each column to be duplicated by itself, but not the pair of them. So you can have multiple references to the same `car`, and multiple references to the same `item_list`, but not multiple links between the same `car` and `item_list`.

```
CREATE TABLE `car_item` (
   `id_car_item` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `car_idcar` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `item_list_iditem_list` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_car_item`),
   UNIQUE KEY `car_idcar_iditem_list_UNIQUE` (`car_idcar`, `item_list_iditem_list`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_car_has_item_list_car1` FOREIGN KEY (`car_idcar`) REFERENCES `car` (`idcar`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `fk_car_has_item_list_item_list1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_list_iditem_list`) REFERENCES `item_list` (`iditem_list`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

See [Creating UNIQUE constraint on multiple columns in MySQL Workbench EER diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376413/creating-unique-constraint-on-multiple-columns-in-mysql-workbench-eer-diagram)

Comment: Dear @Barmar, If I mark `car_idcar, item_list_iditem_list` as unique keys for the middle table, how I can link `a car to multiple items` and `multiple car to an item`?

Comment: This is a composite key. Each column is allowed to be used multiple times, it's only the **combination** that has to be unique.

Comment: So you can have `(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)`, but you can't have `(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)`

Comment: wait me a few sec, I'm testing what you have explained again.

Comment: Dear @Barmar, I can not put those `(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)` I paste my error log here http://pastebin.com/cgdug34Y

Comment: You must have a unique index other than the one I showed in my answer, like `ADD UNIQUE KEY car_idcar_UNIQUE (car_idcar)`.

Comment: Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE car_item` to the question.

Comment: Dear @Barmar, I added `show create table car_item` to the question.

Comment: Dear @Barmar, i'm adding my `forward_engineering_query` to the question.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the correct table definition.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, let me try it first.

Comment: Dear @Barmar, Your solution is works, But It's seems can not be done via `Workbench forword_engineering` method. I might have to learn SQL more and more. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376413/creating-unique-constraint-on-multiple-columns-in-mysql-workbench-eer-diagram

Comment: you helped me a lot, i will read that link for EER workbench.